Error with the width of elements on the responsive page
I had a problem with a page I'm developing. For some reason, when I readjusted the size of the page to test the responsiveness, in netbook resolutions, the content does not occupy the entire screen but only a part. The strange thing is that when inspecting the elements, they all appear to have the same width as the screen, when at first glance it seems that they do not.
I tried to assign it to occupy the entire width of the screen but it clearly didn't work
Another thing that I found strange is that it depends on the browser, in some it works fine and in others it happens what I mentioned. In Edge and Brave it doesn't work, in Chrome and Firefox it does.
React component:
import "../styles/contacto.css"
import Footer from "../components/Footer"

function Contacto() {
    return(
        <>
            <main>
                <h2>Nuestras Sedes</h2>
                <div className="sedes">
                    <div className="sede">
                        <h3>Sede</h3>
                        <p>Dirección</p>
                        <p>Teléfon</p>
                        <p>Email</p>
                        <img src="/src/assets/mapa1.png" alt="" />
                    </div>         
                </div>
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default Contacto

css
main {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sedes {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.sede {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.sede h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sede p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.sede img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1444px) {
    body {
        font-size: 15px; 
    }
    .sede {
        max-width: 280px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1240px) {
    body {
        font-size: 14px; 
    }
    .sede {
        max-width: 260px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    
    body {
        font-size: 13px; 
    }
    .sedes {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .sede {
        max-width: 90%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
    body {
        font-size: 12px; 
    }

    .sede {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 5px;
    }
}

The problem is not with one page in particular, but with all of them.

Sorry, I thought I had uploaded it. I'll upload it there.

In JSX, you would normally use className, not class to add a class. Is that a typo in the example, or the actual code?

It was just a typo

Can you provide us an image?
